# In what way is Jorge Amado's The Discovery of America by the Turks a modernist novel?

Tags: history-of-literature, portuguese-language, jorge-amado, discovery-of-america-by-the-turks

The Wikipedia article about Jorge Amado's [*The Discovery of America by the Turks* / *A Descoberta da América pelos Turcos*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Discovery_of_America_by_the_Turks) describes this work as "a Brazilian Modernist novel", even though it was written in 1994, long after the heyday of literary modernism.

When exactly modernism ended has been debated. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modernism#After_World_War_II_(mainly_the_visual_and_performing_arts)) cites  Clement Greenberg as an example of a scholar who sees modernism ending in the 1930s. The article adds,

> In fact many literary modernists lived into the 1950s and 1960s, though generally they were no longer producing major works. The term "late modernism" is also sometimes applied to Modernist works published after 1930. Among modernists (or late modernists) still publishing after 1945 were Wallace Stevens, Gottfried Benn, T. S. Eliot, Anna Akhmatova, William Faulkner, Dorothy Richardson, John Cowper Powys, and Ezra Pound.

Amado is not mentioned in that article or in the article [lierary modernism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_modernism). In fact, South-American authors are simply ignored in these articles.

To the extent that Amado's last novel is modernist, it would be an example of late modernism. Hence my question: What characteristics of *The Discovery of America by the Turks* make this work a modernist novel? Or is the claim incorrect?